# How to add WSSE header in web service request

Tags: web-services, biztalk, wsse, biztalk-2016

I have to add password text in WSSE header request before sending the request to another system from BizTalk. Have coded a helper class to generate the Nonce and send attached it to WCF headers inside orchestration. When testing getting error saying "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized"

Comment: First of all you will need to capture the payload and headers going to the other system, using either something like Fiddler or Wireshark, and compare it against the expected payload and headers.  Usually I would put this sort of logic in a EndpointBehavior rather than in the Orchestration.

Comment: Wanted to put the same on endpoint behavior but since the password to access the endpoint is dynamic so to accommodate dynamic calling of web service created orchestration and trying to put wsse header logic also there.

Comment: The same code in your helper class, can be made part of your end-point behaviour. For example, here is a OAuth behaviour for SalesForce that gets a OAuth token https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30681.calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-biztalk-server-multiple-endpoints.aspx